# Why Emite package does not have Conversation class and session.onStateChanged does not accept arguments (Listener<Session.State>(){})?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp

I found a link showing a basic example of how to use Emite voice chat in GWT (https://code.google.com/p/emite/wiki/BasicExample)

However, it does not explain step by step clearly.

I downloaded `emite-0.5.0.jar` & `suco-0.6.0.jar` & put them into `lib` folder.

```
 <module>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
  <inherits name="com.calclab.emite.core.EmiteCore" />
  <inherits name="com.calclab.emite.im.EmiteIM" />

  <entry-point
    class="com.calclab.examples.emite.basics.client.EmiteBasicsEntryPoint" />

  <servlet path="/proxy" class="de.spieleck.servlets.ProxyServlet"/>

</module>
```

and the code

```
    public class EmiteBasicsEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    private TextArea area;

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        initOutput();

        // Suco is a facade that give access to every emite component we need
        // ******** 0. Configure connection settings *********
        final Connection connection = Suco.get(Connection.class);
        connection.setSettings(new BoshSettings("proxy", "localhost"));
        // ...but there's a module, BrowserModule, that allows to configure
        // the connections settings in the html directly

        // ******** 1. Session *********
        // Session is the emite component that allows us to login/logout among
        // other things
        final Session session = Suco.get(Session.class);

        // Session.onStateChanged allows us to know the state of the session
        session.onStateChanged(new Listener<Session.State>() {
            public void onEvent(final Session.State state) {
                print("Session state: " + state);
            }
        });

        // Session.login and Session.logout are our xmpp entrance and exit
        session.login(uri("test1@localhost"), "test1");

        // After login, we can send messages ...
        session.send(new Message("Hello", uri("test2@localhost")));
        // ... or receive messages ...
        session.onMessage(new Listener<Message>() {
            public void onEvent(final Message message) {
                print("Message arrived: " + message.getBody());
            }
        });

        // ******** 2. ChatManager *********
        // ... but probably you prefer to use the a powerful abstraction: Chat
        final ChatManager chatManager = Suco.get(ChatManager.class);
        final Conversation chat = chatManager.openChat(uri("test2@localhost"), null, null);
        // with chats you don't have to specify the recipient
        chat.send(new Message("Hello test2"));
        // and you only receive messages from the entity you specified
        chat.onMessageReceived(new Listener<Message>() {
            public void onEvent(final Message message) {
                print("Message from test2 arrived: " + message.getBody());
            }
        });

        // ******** 3. Roster *********
        // As always, Suco is our friend...
        final Roster roster = Suco.get(Roster.class);
        // ... we're in asynchronous world... use listeners
        // onRosterRetrieved is fired when... surprise! the roster is retrieved
        roster.onRosterRetrieved(new Listener<Collection<RosterItem>>() {
            public void onEvent(final Collection<RosterItem> items) {
                print("We have the roster");
                for (final RosterItem item : items) {
                    print("Roster item: " + item);
                }
            }
        });
        // we can track changes in roster items (i.e. roster presence changes)
        // using Roster.onItemUpdated
        roster.onItemUpdated(new Listener<RosterItem>() {
            public void onEvent(final RosterItem item) {
                print("Roster item changed:" + item);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initOutput() {
        area = new TextArea();
        RootPanel.get().add(area);
        print("Welcome to emite basics example.");
    }

    /**
     * a helper method to output messages
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    private void print(final String message) {
        area.setText(area.getText() + "\n" + message);
    }

}
```

However, the 2 above packages do not have `Conversation` class & there is no `uri` method in the example.

ALso, the below code got error `The method onStateChanged(Listener<Session>) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (new Listener<Session.State>(){})`

```
session.onStateChanged(new Listener<Session.State>() {
        public void onEvent(final Session.State state) {
            print("Session state: " + state);
        }
    });
```

It seems that the document did not write carefully.

*Does anyone know how to use Emite voice chat in GWT? or giving a really simple example demonstrating how to use* `Emite in GWT`?

Updated: I used the `emite-0.4.6.jar`, and I do not have all the bove error except that I could not see the Conversation class. Ok, now, I removed all code relating to Conversation class & then compile the app & found these errors:

```
    Loading modules
   henry.naturalspeaking.NaturalSpeaking
      Loading inherited module 'henry.naturalspeaking.NaturalSpeaking'
         Loading inherited module 'com.calclab.emite.core.EmiteCore'
            Loading inherited module 'com.calclab.suco.Suco'
               Loading inherited module 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log'
                  [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/allen_sauer/gwt/log/gwt-log.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
               [ERROR] Line 3: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:315)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
               [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
               [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:371)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:254)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1026)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:570)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:456)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1094)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
            [ERROR] Line 5: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:336)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:333)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    tSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    ......
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Comment: As is, this is too broad. Please narrow down to a specific issue (you can ask more than one question if needed).

Answer (score 0):

> However, the 2 above packages do not have Conversation class & there is no uri method in the example.

- `Connection` is in the jar named `emite-0.5.0.jar`, see `/com/calclab/emite/core/client/bosh/` or [in the sources tree](https://code.google.com/p/emite/source/browse/trunk/emite/src/main/java/com/calclab/emite/core/client/bosh/Connection.java).
- The method `uri()`, is a static import, see the source tree linked above (`import static com.calclab.emite.core.client.xmpp.stanzas.XmppURI.uri;`).

> Also, the below code got error "The method onStateChanged(Listener) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (new Listener(){})"

According to [the sources](https://code.google.com/p/emite/source/browse/trunk/emite/src/main/java/com/calclab/emite/core/client/xmpp/session/Session.java#162), there is a `onStateChanged(final Listener<State> listener)`, but in version 0.5, the signature is -- *as stated by your error message* -- different. You have to use `onStateChanged(final Listener<Session> listener)`:

```
 session.onStateChanged(new Listener<Session>() {
    public void onEvent(final Session session) {
        print("Session state: " + session.getState());
    }
 });
```

---

I think you should use samples presents in the 0.5 jar (see "x" prefixed folders) so you don't use samples not compatible with version 0.5.

Comment: Also note that the comments on your link "https://code.google.com/p/emite/wiki/BasicExample" are insightful.

Comment: There is COnnection class but we do not have Conversation class,

Comment: could you tell me where is Conversation class (not Connection class)?

Comment: I got this error: Loading inherited module 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log'
                  [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/allen_sauer/gwt/log/gwt-log.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

Comment: I gave you all you need to figure out, `chatmanager.open()` returns a `Chat` object in 0.6, see  https://code.google.com/p/emite/source/browse/trunk/emite/src/main/java/com/calclab/examples/emite/basics/client/EmiteBasicsEntryPoint.java#80

Comment: Now I added gwt-log-2.5.3.jar into the lib and the above error dissapear, but now I got other error: Unable to load module entry point class com.calclab.emite.browser.client.BrowserModule (see associated exception for details). 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required meta-attribute emite.httpBase not found.
    at com.calclab.emite.browser.client.DomAssist.getMeta(DomAssist.java:105)
    at com.calclab.emite.browser.client.AutoConfig.configureConnection(AutoConfig.java:80)

Comment: Read your error message ("Required meta-attribute emite.httpBase not found") then **read** the tutorial page you linked in your question ( http://code.google.com/p/emite/wiki/BasicExample).

Comment: I added "<meta id="emite.httpBase" content="proxy" />
        <meta id="emite.host" content="localhost" />
        <meta id="emite.onClose" content="logout" />
", but still have the same error

Comment: Besides, I am using GWTP, and seem this code is for GWT. I am not sure if that is the problem

Comment: Now, I took the example from EmiteBasicsEntryPoint.java inside the package emite-0.4.6, this time I have no error whatsoever, but this time the text did not show "Hello test2", but showed "Session state: connecting
Session state: error
Session state: disconnected". So what does that mean?